# onCompletion being triggred, not onException

Tags: exception, cxf, apache-camel, onexception

This is a varition of the question, I asked in [Camel's CXF component not catching onException(Exception.class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481466/camels-cxf-component-not-catching-onexceptionexception-class)

I have implemented the solution which Claus suggested in the above but its not working. **I don't understand why onCompletion is being triggered when I've set HandleFault = true at the global level.**

I've modified the code A LOT, hence asking the same question but with a few changes.

My Route looks like this: Route 1(camel-cxf endpoint) -> Route 2(direct) -> Route 3(direct). In Route 3, I am throwing a WebApplicationException(I am again wrapping this in MyWSException), which is a runtime exception.

I've set HandleFault to true at the context level.

```
getContext().setHandleFault(true);
```

My onException handle at the global level looks like this:

```
onException(Exception.class, MyWSException.class)
        .process(new Processor(){
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("In onException Exception and IServicesWSException");
            }
        })
        .to("direct:IServicesWSExceptionHandler");
```

I also have a local one(Route specific), which looks like this.

```
from("cxf:bean:ordermanagementservice")
        .routeId("ordermanagementservice")
        .startupOrder(2)
        .onException(Throwable.class)
            .handled(true)
            .setBody().simple(PROCESS_RESULT_FAILED)
            .process(new Processor(){
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader(AuditConstants.AUDIT_MAP_KEY.getValue(), AuditParam.AUDIT_ATTR_STATUS_ORDER);
                }
            })
            .beanRef("AuditManager", "audit")
            .to("direct:IServicesWSExceptionHandler")
            .end()
```

My onCompletion(Route specific) looks like this.

```
.onCompletion()
            .setBody().simple(PROCESS_RESULT_SUCCESS)
            .process(new Processor(){
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader(AuditConstants.AUDIT_MAP_KEY.getValue(), AuditParam.AUDIT_ATTR_STATUS_ORDER);
                }
            })
            .beanRef("AuditManager", "audit")
            .end()
```

Please help. I apologize if the question seems as a repeat. Very desperate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand onCompletion is called regardless if its a success or a failure.

But, I want the onException to be called..

Comment: I got what was happening. The policy of Route 1 doesn't apply to Route 3, even though Route1 was the original caller.

Now, set an onException at each Route being called and its now working well.